# Sumar input de usuario a valor de base de datos

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Yo tengo un formulario, donde el usuario estaria introduciendo un valor numerico, como yo hago para que ese mismo valor, se le adicione, al que ya tiene en su base de datos. Donde el formulario tiene un modelo y el valor al que se le sumaria estuviera en otro modelo.

```
views.py 

def solit(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    form = addiForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form = (form.cleaned_data['dias_adicion'] + LocalUsers.d_pendientes)
            form.save()
        return redirect ('index')
    else:
        form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form}, 
args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una vía puede ser:

```
dias_a_sumar = form.cleaned_data['dias_adicion']
addiObj = form.save(commit=False)
addiObj.d_pendientes + dias_a_sumar
addiObj.save()
```

Fíjate en el commit=False, este no guarda aún el objeto.
User CameCase tipo addiObj no es pythonico, lo mejor es usar addi_obj